# Django-Allauth not allowing me to access the login with facebook Python2.7 Django

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-allauth

I have tried to login with `django-Allauth` application in `Django 1.11.5`. I am using `python 2.7`.

The problem is: when I logged in with my account I got a clean chit ... successful login. I have submitted the application but the review failed as there was flaw in the login of the application using the other user.

Then I sent that application to my friend to test it and he found the same issue. I wonder why I do not see anything and I get a successful login, while my friend or the facebook app reviewer didn't.

See the following codes and please let me know what I might need to improve to make the application work accordingly.

**settings.py**

```
SITE_ID = 1

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'SCOPE': ['email', 'user_posts', 'user_photos', 'user_about_me', 'user_likes', 'user_friends'],
        'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        'FIELDS': [
            'email',
            'name',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'posts',
            'about',
            'picture.type(large)',
            'likes',
            'cover',
            'taggable_friends.limit(1){name,picture.type(large){url},first_name}',

        ],
        'LIKED_FIELD': [
            'link',
            'name',
            # 'picture.type(normal){url}',
        ],
        # 'EXCHANGE_TOKEN': True,
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': True,
        'VERSION': 'v2.10',
    }
}
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',
)
```

**template.html**

```
<form method="post" action="/fileprocess/" enctype="multipart/form-data"  class="box has-advanced-upload" id="sendfile">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}

                 <a href="/accounts/logout/" title="Log out from the website">

                    <button type="button" class="fb__submit btn-space">
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook" style="font-size: 250%" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        Log out
                    </button>
                </a>

                    <!--<a href="/accounts/logout/"><div>Sign Out</div></a>-->


        {% else %}


                <a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="js_sdk"%}" title="Login with Facebook">
                    <button type="button" class="fb__submit btn-space">Login in with
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook" style="font-size: 250%" aria-hidden="true">

                        </i>

                    </button>
                </a>
            <!--You are not logged in-->
            <!--<a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="js_sdk" %}">Facebook Connect</a>-->
        {% endif %}
            </form>
```

Please share your insights and improvements for the application.

The following image is what I am getting after login fail:

[image: error showing image]

Comment: Are the API_KEY and SECRET_KEY set on the server and not only on your local machine?

Comment: The API_KEY and SCRET_KEY is set using the admin panel of my application. I guess that means it is on server itself.

Comment: I followed this tutorial for that purpose: https://godjango.com/65-starting-with-django-allauth/

Comment: By what I see here, I can't find an issue. I'd connect with Teamviewer to my friends system, enable debug-mode and check what happens on his side with `django-debug-toolbar` enabled, too. This way you'll hopefully get some further insights whats wrong

Comment: @user1 What way the debug tool will help? I am a bit confused.. I am checking the documentation but ound nothing.

Comment: You could intercept redirections, have a look at requests and response informations within Django and have an in depth look at what's happening where and why.

Comment: do you got any updates on this? I did a small demo app on my machine and couldn't reproduce this one :(

Comment: @user1 I tried but I still got the same issue. Hence, I have kept the scope as it is and removed the `FIELDS` except `email`. The application then ran fine.